# Systemd service creation of Prometheus

Tags: systemd, services, oracle-linux, prometheus-exporter

Oracle Linux 8

Trying to start prometheus from systemd and getting the `status=203/EXEC` error.  I can copy/paste the commands from `/etc/systemd/system/prometheus.service` and it will start without error. The prometheus user (no login) and group exist. This is my **prometheus.service:**

```
[Unit]
Description=Prometheus
Documentation=https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/overview/
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment="GOMAXPROCS=1"
User=prometheus
Group=prometheus
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/prometheus \
  --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml \
  --storage.tsdb.path=/var/lib/prometheus \
  --web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles \
  --web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries \
  --web.listen-address=0.0.0.0:9090 \
  --web.external-url=

SyslogIdentifier=prometheus
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: What is the output of `sudo journalctl -xe --unit=prometheus.service`?

Comment: Another tip: test the command under the prometheus user, this should allow you to log in as prometheus: `su -s /bin/bash prometheus`